# What is this plastic connector called?

Tags: refrigerator, connectors

I found this connector leaking a little under my refrigerator. What is it called? I either need to fix it or replace it - suggestions welcome.

[image: fridge water line connector]

Comment: Just curious, why is this connector there at all? Why isn't the yellow pipe directly connected to that thing on the left side?

Comment: @puck   Someone cut the yellow hose too short/did not measure right is the usual answer when you see this.

Comment: The Union was part of the factory assembly. My guess is that the door (clear tube) is built at a different location and they add the join once the door is put on the fridge.

Comment: You'd need some kind of connector to remove the door (to get through a tight space).

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Let's just say I found that out the hard way. The clear tube is scratched up because I tried removing the door with a bit of a tug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about the size, but probably a 1/4 John Guest union.

Try pushing the pipes together to seat them better in the union.

Comment: If pushing them together fails, they are like $5 at the orange big box store.

Comment: Is this pressurized for water supply to the refrigerator for ice maker or cold water? The sealing bushings look pulled out on the outside of the bend. Maybe squaring them will stop the leak. Is the direction of flow from left to right in the picture?

Comment: The bend in the hose is probably not helping either.

Comment: @JimStewart I believe this is the cold fridge water line (yellow) going from the  fridge to the front door (clear) for drinking. The direction is from right to left.